# How to show that $\sum_{i=1}^n 1-e^{-n p^i/i} = \Omega(\log n)$ for $0 < p < 1/2$?

Tags: probability, inequality

For a fixed $0 < p < 1/2$, how can I show the following lower bound?

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n 1-\exp\left(- \frac{np^i}{i}\right) = \Omega(\log n) $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $x \mapsto 1 - e^{-x}$ is increasing for $x \geq 0$. Now let $a_n = \tfrac{1}{2}\log_p(1/n)$. Then for any $n$ large enough so that $a_n \leq \sqrt{n}$ holds, we get

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \bigl( 1 - e^{-np^i/i} \bigr)
&\geq \sum_{i \leq a_n} \bigl( 1 - e^{-np^i/i} \bigr) \\
&\geq \sum_{i \leq a_n} \bigl( 1 - e^{-np^{a_n}/\sqrt{n}} \bigr) \\
&= \lfloor a_n \rfloor \bigl( 1 - e^{-1} \bigr).
\end{align*}

Therefore the desired lower bound is obtained.

---

**Addendum.** In fact, we can prove more. Write $p = e^{-\beta}$ for the convenience, i.e., $\beta = \log(1/p)$. Then it turns out that the following holds:

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\log n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \bigl( 1 - \exp\bigl\{ -n/ke^{k\beta} \bigr\} \bigr) = \frac{1}{\beta} $$

- **Lower bound.** For any $0 < r < 1$, let $a_n = \frac{r}{\beta} \log n$. Then for large $n$,

  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{k=1}^{n} \bigl( 1 - \exp\bigl\{ -n/ke^{k\beta} \bigr\} \bigr)
  &\geq \sum_{k \leq a_n} \bigl( 1 - \exp\bigl\{ -n/ke^{k\beta} \bigr\} \bigr) \\
  &\geq \sum_{k \leq a_n} \bigl( 1 - \exp\bigl\{ -n/ a_n e^{\beta a_n} \bigr\} \bigr) \\
  &= \lfloor a_n \rfloor \bigl( 1 - e\bigl\{ -n^{1-r}/a_n \bigr\} \bigr).
  \end{align*}

  This prove that

  $$ \liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\log n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \bigl( 1 - \exp\bigl\{ -n/ke^{k\beta} \bigr\} \bigr) \geq \frac{r}{\beta} $$

  holds for all $r \in (0, 1)$, and so, letting $r \uparrow 1$ produces the lower bound.
- **Upper bound.** Write

  \begin{align*}
  &\sum_{k=1}^{n} \bigl( 1 - \exp\bigl\{ -n/ke^{k\beta} \bigr\} \bigr) \\
  &\quad \leq \int_{0}^{\infty} \bigl( 1 - \exp\bigl\{ -n/xe^{\beta x} \bigr\} \bigr) \, \mathrm{d}
  = - \frac{1}{\beta} \int_{0}^{\infty} \bigl( 1 - e^{-\beta y} \bigr) \, \mathrm{d}W(n/y) \\
  &\qquad = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\beta y} W(n/y)  \, \mathrm{d}y.
  \end{align*}

  In the second step, we utilized the substitution $x=\frac{1}{\beta}W\bigl(\frac{n}{y}\bigr)$, where $W(\cdot)$ is the Lambert W-function. Then by using that $W_0(x) = \mathcal{O}(\log x)$ and $W_0(x) \sim \log x$ as $x \to \infty$, the dominated convergence theorem shows:

  \begin{align*}
  &\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\log n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \bigl( 1 - \exp\bigl\{ -n/ke^{k\beta} \bigr\} \bigr) \\
  &\quad \leq \limsup_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\beta y} \frac{W(n/y)}{\log n}  \, \mathrm{d}y
  = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\beta y}  \, \mathrm{d}y
  = \frac{1}{\beta}.
  \end{align*}